# livewire updated hook not firing inside livewire's form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using livewire 3 to make simple search form

The form :

```
namespace App\Livewire\Forms;

use Livewire\Attributes\Rule;
use Livewire\Form;

class OutputForm extends Form
{
    public $search = '';

    public $employees = '';

    public function updatedSearch()
    {
        $this->employees = \App\Models\Employee::search($this->search)->get();
    }

}
```

blade :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 mx-4">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" wire:model.live.debounce.500ms="form.search"/>
        <label for="search">Find employee</label>           
    </div>
    @if (!is_null($form->employees) || !empty($form->employees))          
    @foreach ($form->employees as $employe)
        <li>{{ $employee->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

It will work if i use regular livewire's component
But Is it possible to fire the updated() hook inside form ?
I already tried it, but it seems that the updated() hook isn't firing, how to solve this ?

Comment: What is `Livewire\Form` in this case?

Comment: @Yinci its the form extraction object according to the documentation https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/forms#extracting-a-form-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things, the Form component does not handle any lifecycle hooks. There's 2 things you can do:

- You can hook the `updated` lifecycle method on your main component (see [docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lifecycle-hooks))

```php
class YourComponent extends Component
{
    public OutputForm $form;
 
    public function updated($field, $value)
    {
        if ($field == 'form.search') {
            $this->form->updatedSearch();
        }
    }

    // OR 
 
    public function updatedFormSearch($value, $field) 
    {
        $this->form->updatedSearch();
        // $field here is 'search', not 'form.search'!
    }
}
```

- You can use the Form component as trait and hook into it with `updatedOutputForm` (see [docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lifecycle-hooks#using-hooks-inside-a-trait)). It isn't documented but just like any `updated` method it returns the `$field` and `$value`

```php
trait OutputForm 
{
    public $search = '';

    //

    public function updatedOutputForm($field, $value)
    {
        if ($field === 'search') {
            $this->updatedSearch();
        }      
    }

    // OR
    
    public function updatedSearch($value)
    {
        // This does trigger, whether it's in this trait or in the main component
    }
}


class YourComponent extends Component
{
    use OutputForm;
}
```

Comment: does the livewire's validation will work inside the traits ?

Comment: @owf Yes, whether you use a `protected $rules` with `$this->validate()` (or `$this->validateOnly()`, or use Rule objects (`#[Rule()]`, it will validate